# Congratulations Aníbal Sánchez

Tags: discussion

Congratulations on your appointment to the Joomla! Community Leadership Team

https://community.joomla.org/blogs/leadership/3071-new-members-for-community-leadership-team-2016.html

Comment: Congrats Aníbal!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: congrats Anibal